# Shell capture substring which is a line below searched substring

Tags: string, bash, shell, text

I am searching through a text file for a particular string and am looking for a number which is a line below this string. So an example below to make it clearer.

This is the content of the text file

```
2017-08-14 14:04:53,836  INFO    - XML File FILE1 is created in /path/to/file
2017-08-14 14:10:04,696  INFO    - #Instances Extracted: 32960
2017-08-14 14:17:52,248 INFO    - XML File FILE2 is created in /path/to/file
2017-08-14 14:41:33,720  INFO    - #Instances Extracted: 119534
```

In the text file I want to search for the string FILE1 and capture the number on the line below it 32960.

What is the best method for this? I was considering searching for FILE1 and then searching for the first instance after this of "Instances Extracted" and capture the number after that, is this the best solution?

Many thanks to any help you can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution:

```
cat file.txt | grep -A1 FILE1 | sed "s/.*Instances Extracted: \([0-9]*\).*/\1/;tx;d;:x"
```

The `grep -A1` pulls the matching line and the next one into stdout, and then the sed will pull the number out (and delete any lines that don't match due to the `;tx;d;:x` at the end)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` without `getline()`:

```
awk 'p==1 {p=0; print $NF } /FILE1/ {p=1}' inputfile
```